# Will SNS expect a response?

Tags: amazon-sns

I have a requirement for which I wish to use AWS SNS.  So basically SNS will call my endpoint and this will in turn start my long task.

Question is does SNS when calling my endpoint wait around for a response as my task can take 5-10 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

SNS will not wait that long for a reply. The timeout is 15 seconds as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.prepare.html.

Comment: Did some reading on this I know you can increase it but not sure if this is best option for firing off a long running task.